# Проблема с присвоением ссылки на массив

Tags: java, массивы

Почему, если во втором конструкторе PizzaType при значении true параметра isLinked, по идее должен не создаваться массив ingredients, а должна передаваться ссылка на массив ingredients объекта типа PizzaType, на основе которого создан другой объект типа PizzaType, и таким образом у двух объектов будут общие ингредиенты (т.е. они будут ссылаться на один и тот же массив), то впоследствии, когда я создаю объект sea на основе classic и к массиву sea добавляю некоторые элементы, а потом отображаю сначала массив ingredients sea, а затем массив ingredients classic, то массив classic не содержит того, что содержит массив sea.

Я вот думаю, если в таком случае это не общий массив, то как тогда был создан массив объекта sea (ведь в конструкторе класса при значении true параметра isLinked не выделяется память для его собственного массива, а лишь передается ссылка на массив другоо объекта).

Просто я хочу, чтобы при установленным в true параметре isLinked объекты имели один общий массив, а при false - у sea создавался свой независимый массив на основе classic.

```
class PizzaType {

String ingredients[];
private double price;

PizzaType(double price, String...v) {
    ingredients = new String[v.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
        ingredients[i] = v[i];
    }
    this.price = price;
}

PizzaType(PizzaType pt, boolean isLinked) {
    if(isLinked) ingredients = pt.ingredients;
    else {
        ingredients = new String[pt.ingredients.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; ++i) ingredients[i] = pt.ingredients[i];
    }
    price = pt.getPrice();
}

void showIngredients() {
    for(int k = 0; k < ingredients.length; ++k)
    System.out.println(ingredients[k]);
}

void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

void addIng(String...ing) {
    int k, len = ingredients.length;
    String[] a = new String[len + ing.length];
    for(k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
        a[k] = ingredients[k];
    }
    for(k = len; k < len + ing.length; ++k) {
        a[k] = ing[k - len];
    }
    ingredients = a;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    // Classic Pizza
    PizzaType classic = new PizzaType(200, "cheese", "sausage", "tomato");
    
    // Vegetable Pizza
    PizzaType vegetable = new PizzaType(280, "tomato", "onion", "olives", "cucumber");

    // Mix based on Classic without a link
    PizzaType mix = new PizzaType(classic, false);
    mix.addIng("mushrooms", "cucumber");
    System.out.println("Mix pizza ingredients:");
    mix.showIngredients();
    System.out.println("Classic pizza ingredients:");
    classic.showIngredients();
    
    // Sea based on Vegetable with a link
    PizzaType sea = new PizzaType(vegetable, true);
    sea.addIng("fish", "squid");
    System.out.println("Sea pizza ingredients:");
    sea.showIngredients();
    System.out.println("Vegetable pizza ingredients:");
    vegetable.showIngredients();            
}
```

Результат кода:

```
Mix pizza ingredients:
cheese
sausage
tomato
mushrooms
cucumber
Classic pizza ingredients:
cheese
sausage
tomato
Sea pizza ingredients:
tomato
onion
olives
cucumber
fish
squid
Vegetable pizza ingredients:
tomato
onion
olives
cucumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в конструкторе используете `ingredients = pt.ingredients`, что присваивает ссылку на массив ингредиентов из объекта `pt` массиву ингредиентов этого класса. Вы не скопировали массив, а просто присвоили ссылку на другой массив.

Решение:

1. Поэлементное копирование массива
2. Вызов pt.ingredients.clone(), что склонирует массив и "отделит" его от другого списка ингредиентов

Если необходимо "связать" два массива, то ошибка происходит в методе `addIng`. Здесь Вы создаете новый массив, соответственно ссылка на предыдущий массив заменяется новой, и он никак не связан с тем, что был присвоен в конструкторе.

Самый удобный способ исправить это - использовать List в качестве коллекции для хранения ингредиентов. При добавлении новых ингредиентов в список его ссылка не будет меняться.

Таким образом код должен быть таким:

```
class PizzaType {
    private List<String> ingredients;
    private double price;

PizzaType(double price, String...v) {
    ingredients = new ArrayList(v);
    this.price = price;
}

PizzaType(PizzaType pt, boolean isLinked) {
    if(isLinked) ingredients = pt.ingredients;
    else ingredients = new ArrayList(pt.ingredients);
    price = pt.getPrice();
}

void showIngredients() {
    for(int k = 0; k < ingredients.size(); ++k)
    System.out.println(ingredients[k]);
}

void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

void addIng(String...ing) {
    for(String i : ing) {
        ingredients.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если я хочу, чтобы с добавлением элементов к массиву sea/vegetable, у меня также добавлялись эти же элементы к массиву vegetable/sea, что тогда нужно делать? Ведь по сути для этого я и объявил параметр isLinked, который, принимая значения true или false, должен говорить методу либо присваивать ссылку на другой массив (как в случае с sea и vegetable), либо просто создавать новый на основе другого (как в случае с mix и classic).

Comment: обновлю ответ сейчас

Comment: А разве в строке ingredients = a метода addIng у нас  не присваивается ссылка на новый массив?

Comment: В вашем коде да, присваивается. но присваивается ссылка на новый созданный массив. Который хоть и содержит те элементы, что и раньше, но это совершенно новый массив и никак не связан больше с ингредиентами vegetables

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, то проголосуйте за него и отметьте как решение, пожалуйста

Comment: Да, точно, сразу не понял. Спасибо большое!